# "Message description not found" warnings in strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I receive tons of annoying warnings from my strings.xml. To the left of each  declaration I get a warning saying "Message description not found.". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same issue, since I've made an update of the SDK. I found a solution for this issue. Just add a comment before each string in your string.xml file, this will resolve the warnings.

Example below:

```
<!-- Description here -->
<string name="app_name">Test App</string>
```

Comment: So is the warning due to the absence of a comment to describe each string? Terrible! I will try, thank you!

Comment: It appears that if you have description strings for any strings in your app (such as for the localization service), it will throw a warning for every string that's not commented.

Answer (score 1):

A proper fix for this eve though it is older is this:
[NOTE Filenames are not exact in most cases, just a guide]

```
1. In your fragment_main.xml (/ProjectName/res/layout/fragment_main.xml)
change your view and add this: 
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!-- Add this one line below as "contentDescription" refers to this issue 
         of description not found warning by Lint -->
    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

2. The @string references the strings in your strings.xml and the name 
   of the string itself is "description"
   So in your ProjectName/res/values/strings.xml add:

   <string name="description">Variables</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the resource in strings.xml and then you can try to refresh. If you still have an error, try to close project and then reopen it. If all that doesn't work try to clean the project.

Comment: -1 because OP doesn't have an error and these are no more than the classical troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will fix it. Add `android:contentDescription=”@string/description”` to your xml. The purpose of description is for accessibility. It isn't needed, and your app will run normal without it. However, it is good practice to be in the habit of including it.

Comment: Thank you, in which xml and in which tag should I add it?

Comment: The view that is using the `strings.xml`. So where you declare your attributes.

Comment: @Binghammer The warnings are in the 'strings.xml', there are no warnings/errors in the layout files. There are many views using strings, are you saying that all of them need a content description attribute?

Comment: @BenWilkinson They don't *need* anything. It's for accessibility purposes.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily disable this lint warning.

Right click the warning in the 'Problems' window, and click 'Quick Fix'. Then you can disable the check for the file, the project, or everywhere.

Comment: disabling warnings it's never a solution. I explain: if I want to clear warnings it's because I care about warnings. A better solution would be to simply close my eyes.